# Loop through the string Array take each item at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, for-loop

So I have a Array:

```
   string[] myArray = txtStudentIDList.Text.Split(new Char[] { ',' });


    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var ice = new DAL(Context, "UpdateData");

        ice.AddParam("ClientID", myArray[i]);

    }
}
```

This is the String Array has some values in it what I want to do is this:

```
 // eg myrray has the values of "1234","12344"
    string Id = myarray myArray[i];
```

I want this id to take the value one by one each time it comes in the for loop above take the first value then next time it comes in the loop take the second value so it could update data by given client ID: for example:

```
 // eg myrray has the values of "1234","12344"
1st time in the loop the id="1234" second time it comes in the look id = "12344"
```

The issue right now is this it puts everything in the Array string in one line like this:

`id="1234\r\n12344"`
How do I code this to not have that \r\n and all the values in one string but one by one.

Comment: You need to work on your language it is really hard to understands

Comment: What is the value of `txtStudentIDList.Text` before you split it? What is the contents of `myArray` after the split?

Comment: What is an "Array string"? What is a sample of `txtStudentIDList`? What does each `myArray[i]` consist of? Your code looks okay...

Comment: Are you sure you need to split on a comma alone? It looks like you have an unexpected CRLF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears that txtStudentIDList is not a comma separated list, but a \r\n separated list.

change your first line:

```
string[] myArray = txtStudentIDList.Text.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
```

to:

```
string[] myArray = txtStudentIDList.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Once your myArray object has the appropriate values the rest of your code here should work as expected.

the Split method was found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: by making the first line         string[] myArray = txtStudentIDList.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" });
 it says cant convert from string to char

Comment: my apologies.  That definition of Split requires both arguments, or else C# thinks your using the definition for Split(char []).  Try after the edit

Comment: @user7396598 You should never need to escape the `\r` and `\n` as you suggested.

Comment: @NetMage thanks.  I have removed that bit from the answer to prevent any confusion.